# how do I concat a variable with some hardcode value in PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

how do I concat a variable with some hardcode value  in PIG

A = LOAD 'data' as (f1:chararray, f2:chararray, f3:chararray);

X = FOREACH A GENERATE CONCAT("BIG",f3);

Expected output :

(apache,open,BIGsource)

(hadoop,map,BIGreduce)

(pig,pig,BIGlatin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pig doesn't support double quotes, so you need to change the hard-coded value from double to single quotes.

```
X = FOREACH A GENERATE f1,f2,CONCAT('BIG',f3);
```

**Update:**
You can use `REPLACE` function to remove the double quotes from input.
sample example below

**data**

```
"apache","open","source"
"hadoop","map","reduce"
"pig","pig","latin"
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'data' USING PigStorage(',') AS (f1:chararray, f2:chararray, f3:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE REPLACE(f1,'"',''),REPLACE(f2,'"',''),CONCAT('BIG',REPLACE(f3,'"',''));
DUMP B
```

**Output:**

```
(apache,open,BIGsource)
(hadoop,map,BIGreduce)
(pig,pig,BIGlatin)
```

Comment: I input data as "apache","open","source" if I concat with hardcode value Im getting output as Big"source" but how to remove the "" from the input data?

Comment: I actually removed the quotes from source itself. Your solution is also working